# Flutter: floating button inside each row of listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, flutter-windows

I am learning Flutter. The version I am using is Flutter 1.24.0-10.2.pre • channel dev.

I am working on a project that could run on Windows 10 and Android. Therefore I use the dev channel. The project is a notebook, each note has a title, content and tags. I use a ListView to show the titles.

Is it possible to show an edit icon on that row and covers parts of the title when user tap the title? The icon is hidden when the row is not highlighted, tapped.

I did try to put a Scaffold inside a Scaffold, but it fail.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you give me screenshot to better understanding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a stateful widget, then `onTap: () setState(() => listViewTileTabbed[index] = true),`

and in the tile you also add
`leading: listViewTileTabbed[index] ? Text('Edit') : null,`